# Confusion in symbols in group theory

Tags: group-theory, notation

Can someone please explain what does the * sign above the right side of brackets mean in the first line of this paragraph? And what does that arrow mean?

In second line, what does G{0} mean? What does \ represent? 
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A03sH.jpg)

Comment: What does * mean? It could have been just {0,1}. right?

Answer (score 1):

$\{0,1\}^*$ denotes the [free monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_monoid) on the alphabet $\{0,1\}$. The arrow means that $h$ is a (hash) function from $\{0,1\}^*$ to $G_1^*$.

Comment: thanks a lot for guidance!

Answer (score 0):

Usually the curly brackets represent set notation, i.e. {1,2,3} would represent a set consisting of 3 elements from the natural numbers, here they have used the symbol 0 to represent the neutral or zero element of the group and denote the set containing only 0 as {0}.

The operator \ is usually the "set-minus" operator. It is a way of removing subsets from a set much like the subtraction operator. So for example {1,2,3} \ {1} = {2,3}

Comment: thank you vey much sir!

Comment: You're welcome :)